# Control dependency tree logic - find circular dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, circular-dependency

I have created an application where users can create models. The model is a collection of controls with some formulas. For ex,

```
Control1 = 1 + 2
Control2 = {Control1} + 5
Control3 = {Control2} / {Control1}
Control4 = {Control2} * {Control1}
Control5 = 6 + 1
Control6 = {Control5} + {Control3}
Control7 = {Control6} + {Control8}
Control8 = {Control6} + {Control7}
```

and so on..

If you see in the above ex, there is circular dependency between Control7 & Control8. I need to build a tree of this dependency order in formulas. I use regex to identify controlnames in a formula.

Can someone help me to find these circular dependency in c#

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a Graph representation of all models.

After that, you can run some machinery in order to check for evaluation order (this may be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph). In other words, by basically applying Graph Theory you can figure out the dependancies.